# I am seeing/see this person for the first time

Tags: tense

Do you unequivocally consider these wrong?  Are they grammatically wrong or unidiomatic?

> - Have you met him before?
> - No, I am seeing this person for the first time.

> - Have you met him before?
> - No, I see this person for the first time.

Comment: simple present usage: I see this person every time I go to the park.

Comment: Why on earth would they be wrong? Please edit to explain why you have concerns about these; in the meantime, voting to close as lacking details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is perfectly natural and idiomatic (though "No, this is the first time I have seen him" would also be natural).

The second ("I see him") is unidiomatic and sounds like something a non-native speaker would say.